# Opening CD-ROM with bash code

Tags: bash, cd-drive

I have copied this bunch of code from one funny video clip about [How does a programmer swing his baby](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uweJGm7l1Nc). The code is following:

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ l=l ]
do
   #eject cdrom
   eject    
   #pull cdrom track back in
   eject -t
done
```

But it doesn't work for me, when I run it with the command `sh baby_rocker.sh` it performs the code and outputs the following message `eject: unable to find or open device for: "cdrom"` even though I have CD-ROM device on my computer.

How can I make it to work?

Comment: Ubuntu and Parenting advice all in one question got to vote that up

Comment: @Jorge. I have separated the answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to find your cdrom device name (which per the error is not /dev/cdrom).
To find out the cdrom device name from the terminal execute:

```
sudo lshw -C disk
```

It should a device starting with "*-cdrom", the device name is listed at the  "logical name:" field.
Then you need to append the device name to the eject commands on your script, eg:

```
eject /dev/cdrom1
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the answer of [João Pinto](https://askubuntu.com/users/742/joao-pinto), I changed the code and now it works. So, if you decide to swing your baby with CDROM you can change the code as below and enjoy its functionality:

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ l=l ]
do
   #eject cdrom
   eject /dev/cdrom1
   #pull cdrom track back in
   eject -t /dev/cdrom1
done
```

**Note** that `/dev/cdrom1` is the logic name of my CDROM device. You need to execute `sudo lshw -C disk` command to see your CDROM's logic name.